# Oracle Backup con RMAN, se ejecuta con lentitud

Tags: oracle-11g

Expertos, tengo una versión Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production With the Real Application Clusters and Automatic Storage Management.

Sistema operativo Linux Red Hat 2.6.18-348.12.1.el5.

Database name: dbname

Tamaño de la Database : 92 GB.

Problema: La ejecución de un script, para realizar backups con RMAN se ejecuta en 4 hs 45 minutos. El problema es que durante su ejecución, se ven afectados otros procesos que interactuan con la base de datos.

Las tablas reciben sentencias DML (udpate/insert/delete) cada momento, durante todo el día.

Puedo ver en el log de RMAN, dos momento críticos:

```
Starting backup at 04-04-2017 04:33:59
channel dbname_backup_disk1: starting incremental level 1 datafile backup set
channel dbname_backup_disk1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
input datafile file number=00017 name=file_name ....                                                                        
...   "here all files"                                                                         
channel dbname_backup_disk1: starting piece 1 at 04-04-2017 04:34:00
channel dbname_backup_disk1: finished piece 1 at 04-04-2017 07:22:47
piece handle=+RECOVERY/dbname/backupset/2017_04_04/nnndn1_dbname_level_0_0.2614.940394043 tag=DBNAME_LEVEL_0 comment=NONE
channel dbname_backup_disk1: backup set complete, ***elapsed time: 02:48:48***
```

y:

```
 Starting backup at 04-04-2017 07:46:20
 backup will be obsolete on date 04-07-2017 07:46:20
 archived logs required to recover from this backup will expire when this 
 backup expires
 channel dev1: starting compressed full datafile backup set
 channel dev1: starting piece 1 at 04-04-2017 07:46:21
 channel dev1: finished piece 1 at 04-04-2017 09:22:07
 piece handle=/backup/oracle/backup/DBNAME_940405581_6656_1 tag=TAG20170404T074620 comment=NONE
 channel dev1: backup set complete, ***elapsed time: 01:35:46***
 Finished backup at 04-04-2017 09:22:07
```

Por favor, podrían ayudarme a identificar la clave del problema? para disminuir la duración del backup.

Las líneas abajo, son una proción del script principal, llamado backup.pl. Se ejecuta todos los días a las 2:30am Hora Local (UTC -3)

```
RMAN> run {
    show all;
    CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 1 DAYS;
    configure controlfile autobackup on;
    CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '+RECOVERY/DBTARGET/%F';
    CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT '+RECOVERY/DBTARGET/%d_%t_%s_%p';
    allocate channel dbname_backup_disk1 device type disk;
    REPORT OBSOLETE;
    DELETE OBSOLETE;
    recover copy of database with tag 'dbname_LEVEL_0' until time 'sysdate-1';
    backup incremental level 1 cumulative copies=1 for recover of copy with tag 'dbname_LEVEL_0' database include current controlfile;
    backup archivelog all not backed up format '+RECOVERY/DBTARGET/%d_%t_s%s_s%p';
    backup current controlfile for standby;
    delete archivelog until time='sysdate-3';
    release channel dbtarget_backup_disk1;
    sql "create pfile=''/backup/oracle/backup/ros1or01-initdbtarget1-20170404.ora'' from spfile";
    }
    allocate channel for maintenance type disk;
    delete noprompt obsolete device type disk;
    CROSSCHECK BACKUP;
    CROSSCHECK DATAFILECOPY ALL;
    CHANGE ARCHIVELOG ALL CROSSCHECK;
    DELETE EXPIRED ARCHIVELOG ALL;
    REPORT OBSOLETE;
    DELETE OBSOLETE;
    release channel;
    run
    {
    CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '/backup/oracle/backup/%F';
    allocate channel dev1 device type disk format '/backup/oracle/backup/%d_%t_%s_%p';
    backup backupset completed after 'sysdate-3/24';
    backup as compressed backupset datafilecopy all noduplicates KEEP UNTIL TIME 'SYSDATE+3' logs;
    release channel dev1;
    CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '+RECOVERY/DBTARGET/%F';
     }
     quit
    using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
    RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name DBTARGET are:
    CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 1 DAYS;
    CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
    CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
    CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
    CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '+RECOVERY/DBTARGET/%F';
    CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
    CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
    CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
    CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT  '+RECOVERY/DBTARGET/%d_%t_%s_%p';
    CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
    CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
    CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128'; # default
    CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'BASIC' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE ; # default
    CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE; # default
    CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO '/cots/oracle/11.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/snapcf_dbtarget1.f'; # default
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Con el deseo que puedas encontrar solución a tu problema, y queriendo ser realista, no creo que SOes aun tenga un Oracle DBA que tenga los conocimientos necesarios para ayudarte con esto. Si puedes manejar el inglés, puedes intentar hacer la pregunta en la versión inglesa (http://stackoverflow.com). Allí si tienen unos cuantos expertos de Oracle que tienen la experiencia necesaria para contestar esta clase de pregunta.

Comment: Muy útil la aclaración. Gracias.

Comment: Este lugar es para programadores. La pregunta no es de programación más bien es para administradores de Base de Datos. El lugar idóneo más bien sería: https://dba.stackexchange.com/